# API deployed in Azure that doesn't work and i dont know why

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bitbucket

PS: Found solution see below

i deployed my API to azure via bitbucket pipleine using FTP, but whehn i open the link of the API it displays "HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start"

Also when i make a request over postman or the frontend SPA it gives me ther same error.
Im realy lost within azure, becouse so many menus and i cant understand whats the problem. It works fine locally and the pipeline was sucessfully.

Can someone help me understand whats going on?

PS: after some diagnostic ( its menu is not intuitive at all) i found this:

```
: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. The system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
```

My instaled verson is 12.0.0.3 and version 12.0.0.0 dosent even exist on nuget packet manager. Any ideas?

PS: FOUND A SOLUTION

my pipeline is:

https://ibb.co/xC1tcFp

Before the solution the line " cp ./AzureFix/Newtonsoft.Json.dll ./publish" didnt existed and the problem was that the file "Newtonsoft.Json.dll" that bitbucket generated inside the "publish" folder was invalid and when i did "dotnet publish --output publish --configuration release" in my pc that same file was valid.
I found that by using an FTP software to transfer my local files of the "publish" folder to azure and it worked.

So i created a folder in the bitbucket repository with the valid file inside it and in the pipeline i added a line that copy  that file to the "publish" folder generated by bitbucket folder and it works like a charm.

Why did that happen ( the generated file of the bitbucket "publish" was invalid) ?

Answer (score 0):

500.30 errors are startup problems, and can stem from a lot of different things, so giving an exact answer is tough. Check your Startup.cs and Program.cs to ensure everything is correct.  This could be various dependencies such as DB stuff, cache, KeyVault, etc. or issues with ASP.Net versions.

If you have App Insights running for this App Service, check to see if it reports any issues.  Or turn on application logging (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs).

You can also use Kudo to do advanced debugging:  https://zimmergren.net/solving-asp-net-core-3-on-azure-app-service-causing-500-30-in-process-startup-failure/

Comment: hello, ty for the reply, kudo said its becouse my NewTonJson  not found, it says the version is 12.0.0.0 but in reality it is 12.0.0.3 . I already did dotnet publish ... ( that i also do on the pipeline) and it works great locally. And i tried change the version of this package with no success

Comment: If you FTP into the Web App, do you actually see the NewtonSoft.Json.dll in the published web directory?  Could your pipeline be missing something that is preventing it from including that DLL?

Comment: found a solution gona update post soon, thanks
And yes, there was a file NewtonSoft.Json.dll but it was invalid, while the same file inside my local pc was valid. Not sure why, do you know?
In my pipeline i now copy the correct file to the publish folder and then send it to azure and it works good.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if all the NuGet packages are updated -

I struggled with this error for four days and tried every possible suggestion on forum.
And finally after updating all NuGet packages the problem was resolved.

Comment: Were you able to isolate this to a specific NuGet package? Or version? That would be more useful for future readers with this problem?